# Lifetime simulation problem for late entry to the study

Tags: survival, simulation

I was reading a dissertation where the author generates lifetimes ($T_i$) from Exponential distribution with parameter 2 (years). He sets a 5-year study period, so he simulates the censoring times ($C_i$) from $Uniform(0, 5)$ distribution. The observed time is $U_i=min(T_i,C_i)$ with censoring indicator $\Delta_i=(T_i>C_i)$.

The thing that confuses me is, in his dissertation he clearly mentions the type of clinical trial may not start with all the patients joining at the beginning of the study. So late entry to the study is very common in his clinical trial.

Now, if that is true, then he could have simulated a random starting time between 0 to 5 years of study period, say, $T^{start}_i$ from $Uniform(0, 5)$. Then he could generate lifetime $T_i$ from $Exponential(2)$ and censoring time $C_i$ from $Uniform(0, T^{start}_i)$.

Do you think these two processes are equivalent? If not, which one should have been used?

Answer (score 1):

What the author did was fine. I think there's some confusion about what $T$ is though.

In particular, the trial itself is *fixed* at 5 years. Thus, if all patients started at the begin of the trial, then for every patient, $C_i = 5$, and there would be no randomness.

However, patients *don't* all enter at beginning of the trial. They begin trial at $T^{start}_i \sim $ Uniform(0,5). However, *the author implicitly seems to have assumed that the clock for the event time of interest starts when the subject enters the study, not at the very beginning of the study*. Unless this is a very special case, this seems like a very reasonable thing to do.

This means that a subject is only followed for $5 - T^{start}_i$ years, or in other words, $C_i = 5 - T_i^{start}$. If $T_i^{start} \sim$ Unif(0,5), then $5 - T_i^{start}$ is also distributed as a Unif(0,5) distribution.

Comment: I think even if there was no late entry, and all patients started at the same point in time, $C_i$ (which is the censoring time for $i$th subject) could still be distributed as $Uniform(0, 5)$, not only that $C_i=5$. Because it accounts for lost to follow up in the middle of the study (which may happen any time during the study period). What do you think?

Comment: @BlainWaan: in that case, you are talking about two censoring mechanisms: one being lost to follow up and one being termination of the trial. If the author is only considering termination of the trial, what they have done is fine. If they want to include loss to follow up *and* termination of trial (and both were uniformly distributed), then what you described would be more appropriate.